# Single toss of two dice

Tags: probability-or-statistics, homework

Does any one knows answer for this question related to **probability**?

> A pair of fair dice is tossed once. If the sum of the two numbers is greater than 9, the probability that one of the numbers is a 6 is:
>
> A. 2/3
> B. 5/6
> C. 1/6
> D. 1/2
> E. 1/3

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence that the OP has made any effort using *Mathematica* as with the OP’s other recent question (despite @ChrisDengen ‘s excellent answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pairs = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[6], Range[6]], 1];
subset = Select[pairs, Total[#] > 9 &];
contains6 = Length[Select[subset, MemberQ[#, 6] &]];
contains6/Length[subset]
```

> 5/6

Comment: Thanks for the help.